# syntax error, unexpected '' when embedding php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am using php to update some myqsl values from an html form and after the update i want to redirect the user to the page where he/she clicked 'update'. In order to accomplish that i am using the following line

`echo  "<script>var prevUrl='<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];?>';alert('Updated movie $mv  !'); window.location.href=prevUrl;</script>";`

but i get the following error 
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in`

I tried using \ as escape character for the ' in HTTP_REFERER but i had no luck. I tried writing the var with single and double quotes but still no luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have an echo inside an echo. Did you mean to do that?

Comment: Yes. the first echo is because i am writing php and the second is because i want to print this variable an see its value.

Comment: You don't open PHP _in_ PHP. That doesn't make sense. Use concatenation, or variable interpolation, or printf and alike.

Comment: The inner `<?php ?>` tags and the `echo` do not do anything in that string. If you fix the error, they'll actually be in the page source, not executed.  You're getting the error because the array key is quoted. You can use `echo  "<script>var prevUrl='$_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER]';alert('Up...` instead. (Note the absence of quotes around HTTP_REFERER)

Comment: Use one of these two methods: https://ideone.com/MCAUfv

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you. That helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a a php tag and echo command inside your echo command, use variables in your echo like this fo rexample

```
echo  "<script>var prevUrl='".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."';alert('Updated movie $mv  !'); window.location.href=prevUrl;</script>";
```

Comment: That solves my issue but i still cant redirect to the page i want. Maybe you can help me a little bit. I have an array of many results that are organised in pages. Each result has an update button. When you press the update button you go to another page where you can update the values. After updating i want to go back to the results in the same page i was before. The above redirects me back to the update page.

Comment: A simple qway to do that would be to use a get variable something like index.php?lastURL=someurlhere and then in your php code you access that url with $_GET['lastURL']